# How to use GPS log from Nikon D5300?

Tags: nikon, gps, nikon-d5300

I have turned on GPS tracking in my Nikon D5300. It generates a CSV text file with some data.

```
@NikonD5300/ver1.02/wgs84
$GPGGA,192834.00,5053.0214,N,09532.3021,W,1,,,167.6,M,,,,*09
$GPRMC,192834.00,A,5053.0214,N,09532.3021,W,0.0,,220718,,,A*60
$GPGGA,192934.00,5052.8231,N,09532.3527,W,1,,,308.6,M,,,,*0E
$GPRMC,192934.00,A,5052.8231,N,09532.3527,W,0.4,,220718,,,A*68
$GPGGA,193004.00,5052.8242,N,09532.3561,W,1,,,305.6,M,,,,*0E
$GPRMC,193004.00,A,5052.8242,N,09532.3561,W,0.3,,220718,,,A*62
$GPGGA,193034.00,5052.8216,N,09532.3604,W,1,,,311.6,M,,,,*09
$GPRMC,193034.00,A,5052.8216,N,09532.3604,W,0.1,,220718,,,A*62
$GPGGA,193104.00,5052.8166,N,09532.3489,W,1,,,304.6,M,,,,*0C
$GPRMC,193104.00,A,5052.8166,N,09532.3489,W,0.2,,220718,,,A*60
```

Found the website that explains what each field means:

- [GPS: NMEA sentence information](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/)

How can I use this data to place it on the map?

Comment: Have you check if the photos do not have already the GPS coordinates as EXIF record?

Comment: @RomeoNinov They do have location data. But this camera has an option to log location every X minutes. This is the log that it generates

Comment: Your "update" seems like an answer, not part of the question. Put it in an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can visualize the GPS log on different places. For example Google Maps.

1. Go to in My Maps
2. New map. If you do not see Import you can add layer and there import GPS logs
3. Import. There you can add CSV, KLM, GPX files

If you want to convert your log in different format you can use variety of software. I use GPSBabel, you can check [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100049/how-to-use-google-location-history-to-geotag-photos/100052#100052)

This is the command:

```
gpsbabel -w -t -i nmea -f C:/tmp/a.csv -o gpx -F C:/tmp/a/a.gpx
```

Do not use CSV format, instead select NMEA

Edit: You can view images on the map if you use Maps module of Lightroom. And if you export them as `jpeg` or have them in this format you can use Google Photos or Flickr Map module to visualize them on the map

Comment: I tried importing but google maps did not the file format. Converted to CSV extension but still did not figure out which field it wanted to use

Comment: @Ruslan, better convert to `gpx` and then try to upload in google