# Is GIMP allow to add or change geo-tag localization in Exif data? Is there any plugin for that?

Tags: metadata, gimp, geotagging

do you know is it possible to change or add geo-tag localization in Exif data of .JPG photos? Is there any plugin for that? I cannot find any clear answer is it possible from the graphical application on Windows?

Comment: What about other software?

Comment: [How to use Google Location History to geotag photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100049/75526)

Answer (score 3):

In Gimp 2.10, the dialog that you reach via `Image>Metadata>Edit metadata` has a "GPS" tab.

This is a new feature in Gimp 2.10, IIRC.

Edit: it seems to be too buggy to be usable. The longitude and latitude values are truncated if you edit them...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can edit the GPS metadata via Image>Metadata>Edit Metadata.
**It works correctly**,looks like is truncating the data, but it is not.

It changes the format of the data to DMS like( 106deg 5' 12.400" With West in a different field,28deg 39' 37.100" With North in a different field )
**But there is no loss of precision.**

That format is the Default for the Exif Metadata.
Please check: https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q14
"When reading, by default ExifTool reports coordinates in the format
DDD deg MM' SS.SS" otherwise known as human readable format (when we used actual paper maps)
If you copy the data in that format an paste it in Google maps, it won't work.You will need to use the degree symbol ° (Alt 0176) instead of "deg" and Add the (E or W and N or S) as needed.

To see the formats used by Google Maps , please check:
https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?l=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

I hope it helps.
Alex.